# Retrieve value from gin context

Tags: go, go-gin, go-context

I have this code

```
package middleware

import (
    "net/http"

    "github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/irohitb/EmpAdmin/backend/domain"
)




type UserToken struct {
    jwt.StandardClaims
    User domain.UserToken
}


func SessionMiddleware(supabase_secret string) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        userCookie, err := c.Cookie("user")
        if err != nil {
            c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, gin.H{"success": false, "message": "Missing user cookie"})
            return
        }

        token, err := jwt.ParseWithClaims(userCookie, &UserToken{}, func(token *jwt.Token) (interface{}, error) {
            return []byte(supabase_secret), nil
        })
        if err != nil {
            c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, gin.H{"success": false, "message": "Invalid user cookie"})
            return
        }

        claims, ok := token.Claims.(*UserToken)
        if !ok || !token.Valid {
            c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, gin.H{"success": false, "message": "Invalid user token"})
            return
        }

        if !claims.User.IsAdmin {
            c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusUnauthorized, gin.H{"success": false, "message": "Only Admins can perform this action"})
            return
        }

        c.Set("user", claims)
        c.Next()
    }
}
```

Now, in my router, how can I get value set using `c.Get("user")`?

```
package services

import (
    "net/http"
    "strings"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
    "github.com/irohitb/EmpAdmin/backend/config"
    "github.com/irohitb/EmpAdmin/backend/domain"
    "github.com/supabase/postgrest-go"
)


func GetAllUsers(env *config.Env, db *postgrest.Client, group *gin.RouterGroup) {
    group.GET("/:services", func (router *gin.Context) {
        services := strings.Split(router.Param("service"), ",")
        user, exists := router.Get("user")
        if !exists {
            router.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "user information not found in context"})
            return
        }

    
        workspaceId, exists := user.(middleware.UserToken).WorkspaceID
         if !exists {
            router.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": "workspace_id not found in user information"})
            return
        }
        
    })
}
```

This line here is throwing the following error:

```
routes/services/users.go:16:3: services declared and not used
routes/services/users.go:24:54: user.(middleware.UserToken).WorkspaceID undefined (type middleware.UserToken has no field or method WorkspaceID)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a compile time error instead of a runtime error. It's misleading to say that "This line here is throwing following error".

> services declared and not used

This is an implementation restriction in Go, `A compiler may make it illegal to declare a variable inside a function body if the variable is never used` (see [the language spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Variable_declarations)). To fix this issue, either remove `services` or use it.

> user.(middleware.UserToken).WorkspaceID undefined (type middleware.UserToken has no field or method WorkspaceID)

Let's correct some other issues first.

1. There is a syntax error in the [type assertion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions):

   > ```golang
   > workspaceId, exists := user.(middleware.UserToken).WorkspaceID
   > ```

   should be written as:

   > ```golang
   > userToken, exists := user.(middleware.UserToken)
   > if exists {
   >   workspaceId := userToken.WorkspaceID
   > }
   > ```
2. According to `claims, ok := token.Claims.(*UserToken)`, the `claims` has the type `*UserToken` instead of `UserToken`. So `user.(middleware.UserToken)` should be `user.(*middleware.UserToken)`.

Now let's turn back to the error. That means the struct `middleware.UserToken` does not have the field `WorkspaceID`. Maybe it's a field of the struct `domain.UserToken`. Let's assume this is the case, then the overall fix should be:

```golang
userToken, ok := user.(*middleware.UserToken)
if !ok {
    router.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, gin.H{"error": `router.Get("user") is not a UserToken`})
    return
}
workspaceId := userToken.User.WorkspaceId
// use workspaceId below
```